# How to write in a ckdeditor textarea with Cypress?

Tags: 9

i'm trying to create a new node in Drupal 9.
But all my attempts so far have failed when it comes to writing the body text.
The body text is a Ckeditor5 field. I can't write there with Cypress.

I tried the following line with the following error: "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instances')*"

```
  cy.window().then(win => {win.CKEDITOR.instances["html_body"].setData("<p>HTML body</p>");});
```

After several attempts, i tried the jQuery way, so far this solution wont raise any error, but the textarea remains in blank without any text:

```
cy.get('.ck-editor__editable').then($editable => {$editable.focus().html('<p>HTML body</p>');});
```

how can i set text into this field with Cypress?

Comment: I have searched on the internet for the issue and everyone says that ckeditor uses an iframe, but I cannot find any iframe anywhere. :-(

Comment: Never heard of Cypress

Comment: You probably have to wait for the page to be ready, its possible the actual editor hasn't finished loading yet.

Comment: Isn't [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) a JavaScript component testing framework? Are you testing the node creation form?

Comment: yessir to both questions

Comment: Pretty sure I remember reading cke5 doesn't use iframes any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal keeps a list of the active CKEditor 5 instances in JS, you can get them from there. For example to fill all the editors on the page:

```
cy.window().then(win => {
  win.Drupal.CKEditor5Instances.forEach(editor => editor.setData('<p>Test</p>'))
})
```